# How To Update MessageTrace Rest URI

Tags: rest, uri, endpoint, message

Is there is a way to update [this endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj984335.aspx) to just include attachment names?

Alternatively, the only way I can think of to retrieve this information is to execute around 1.2 million REST API calls daily to the O365 web services.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Your goal is unclear, which makes me feel like this could be a case where you're asking how to implement your idea, but there is quite possibly better ways to accomplish the goal than using this endpoint

Comment: We are currently using the message trace endpoint, to download message trace logs into our tool.

The end goal, is we need to be able to include attachment names with the data.

Comment: For my own sake, this is the term I was trying to think of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Answer (score 0):

The second link below does remind me that this question would likely get better answers if posted on https://serverfault.com

---

Because of the [history of how email attachments developed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_attachment#History,_and_technical_detail), the attachments are basically the same as the body of the email, and email header information doesn't necessarily contain any information about them.

It seems like that endpoint is only pulling from the email header data, and therefore quite possibly [would not know about all attachments](https://serverfault.com/questions/443262/can-an-e-mails-headers-tell-you-if-it-has-an-attachment) (although Outlook server could be pre-processing them and adding custom headers, so not 100% no)